# How to fix/restore org-metaright/metaleft behavior after upgrading org-mode (9.5)

Tags: org-mode

**Q:** how do I fix/restore the behavior of `org-metaright` and
`org-metaleft` after an org-mode upgrade?

After upgrading to Emacs v. 28.1 (and therefore org-mode v. 9.5.2)
via Fedora's package manager, `org-metaright` and `org-metaleft`
no longer function as they had in my previous version of org-mode
(v. 9.4).

Specifically: when I run the commands on an entry's header, they
no longer add/subtract whitespace at the beginning of plain list
items to keep them aligned with the header text (as in previous
versions).

An example is as follows.  When running `org-metaright` on the
header of the following entry:

```
* header text

  - item 1 (note that the bullet lines up with the "h" in header)
  - item 2
```

What *should* happen (what used to happen) is the following:

```
** header text

   - item 1 (note that the bullet *still* lines up with the "h" in header)
   - item 2
```

But what now happens is:

```
** header text

  - item 1 (note that the bullet didn't move to line up with the "h" in header)
  - item 2
```

Something *always* breaks with org-mode when I upgrade, which is
why I'm loathe to do it.  I can't imagine this was intended
behavior, so I'm wondering if there's a rogue site file somewhere
screwing things up.

Yes, I get this behavior from `emacs -q`.

Comment: Are you using `org-indent` mode?

Comment: @NickD: no, I am not.  I didn't even know it existed until you mentioned it.

Comment: @NickD: thanks, that got me started down the correct rabbit hole to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can resolve this problem with:

```
(setq org-adapt-indentation t)
```

Here's the first part of the docstring:

```
org-adapt-indentation is a variable defined in ‘org.el’.

Its value is t
Original value was nil

Non-nil means adapt indentation to outline node level.

When set to t, Org assumes that you write outlines by indenting
text in each node to align with the headline, after the stars.
...
```

I'd never even heard about this variable before, and had certainly
never set it myself.  So how did I find out about this?  Only
because @NickD asked about
[`org-indent-mode`](https://orgmode.org/manual/Org-Indent-Mode.html),
which I then inspected, saw a brief mention of
`org-adapt-indentation`, and then looked *it* up.

Presumably someone flipped a switch, turned a knob, or changed a
default somewhere in the bowels of the org source code between 9.4
and 9.5, which results in a treasure hunt for a fix.

Comment: Breaking changes are supposed to be described in the `etc/ORG-NEWS` file. It's always a good idea to peruse the portion of that file between your new and old versions. There is a description of this change in there, together with a link to a FAQ: search for `indent`.

Comment: [Link to an online version of the etc/ORG-NEWS file](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/tree/etc/ORG-NEWS)